# Android product flavors with unique application Ids

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, build.gradle, android-productflavors

Background:
I'm working on an app which is released a few years ago. Now, my app has a considerably large user base. Since, I had only a free version at the time of the launch, I didn't have product flavors configured until now. Let's assume that my application ID is **com.company.app**

**Issue:**

Years later, now I'm going to introduce a paid version of the app and I'm going to use product flavors - **Paid and Free**.

```
    productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId 'com.company.app.free'
    }
    paid {
        applicationId 'com.company.app.paid'
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** According to Android documentation, Google Play Store will treat my app as a brand new app, if I change my application id. If I use the above product flavor block, will I loose my current store listing and my user base? But, since it's just a product flavor, would it matter?

**Question 2:** Do I need to use different application IDs with the product flavors? Can I just use the current application ID on both product flavors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**: You would have two unique apps on the store. They will be handled as two apps with no relation.

**Answer 2:** You can use the same product ID. A simple solution would be to set a boolean resource value to true on the paid version and check that to add some premium features on your app - you could do that using `resValue` on the paid flavor.

Comment: Thanks Natan. I'd like to keep different source sets and dependency list based on the product flavors (Note: paid version doesn't need to keep any ad network dependencies and ad related source codes). Keeping the same application ID on both product flavors, I would not miss out any functionality, right? Please confirm. Thanks

Comment: As for Answer 2, instead of using `resValue` in **build.gradle** use `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` in code, e.g. `BuildConfig.FLAVOR.contains("paid")`

Answer (score 0):

You can add payment features to your existing app without need to change id (Package Name)

Take a lock to **In-app Billing** https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

The application will be just one, the same released years ago. 
For me this is the best solution for free/pay alternatives. Much better than flavors.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different source sets for different flavors, also, you can configure a dependency for a specific build variant. It's hard to have a clear explanation with few words, you can know it clearly from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourceset-build)
.